# PHP while loops causing an infinite load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to upload an image and some strings/numbers using AJAX. The code is working fine (as in, everything is getting into the database) except for one very important problem. I very much want the "character" variable to be unique, and every attempt I use to bring up an error message for trying a character name that has already been taken does not work. Here is my code:

AJAX:

```
function CSubmit() {

clearInterval(MoveDrawTimer);

var a=document.forms['form-id']["thefiles"].value; if (a == "") { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="You must upload an image."; return };

if (showFileSize() > 5000000) { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="File is too big. Maximum size is 5,000,000 bytes."; return };

var accepted = [".gif",".png",".jpg",".jpeg"];

if (Ext in oc(accepted) == true) {

var dataURLToBlob = function(dataURL) {
var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
    var parts = dataURL.split(',');
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = parts[1];

    return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
}

var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
var rawLength = raw.length;

var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
    uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
}

return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType}); }; 

newImage = dataURLToBlob(dataURL); } else { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Cannot send file. Check your extensions."; return };


var canvas = document.getElementById("Cinfo");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400); 

     var TotalSpent = StrPts + IntPts + WisPts + SpdPts + MovPts;

     var theform = document.getElementById("CharName");

     if (theform.value == "") { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Your character must have a name."; return }

     if ( /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(theform.value) ) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Name must contain only letters and / or numbers."; return }

     if (theform.value.length > 14) { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Character names must be 14 characters max."; return }

    if (TotalSpent !== 2) { document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="You must spend exactly 2 points."; return }


 var fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('data', newImage);
 fd.append('character', theform.value);
 fd.append('str', StrPts);
 fd.append('int', IntPts);
 fd.append('wis', WisPts);
 fd.append('spd', SpdPts);
 fd.append('mov', MovPts);



    //beginning of server transmission. above is javascript front end authentication.


              //sending the following information:


              //theform.value // character name
              //StrPts, IntPts, WisPts, SpdPts, MovPts // the character stats

               var xmlhttp;

               if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {       // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                  else
                  {       // code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }


               xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ xmlhttp.addEventListener("progress", document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Please wait . . ." , false);
                                                      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                                                      if (xmlhttp.responseText.length <= 14) {
                                                          document.getElementById("info").innerHTML="Congratulations, " + xmlhttp.responseText + " has been approved.";
                                                          SelectScreen();} } }


               xmlhttp.open("POST","CHunique.php",true);
               xmlhttp.send(fd);
```

};

As you can see, I am appending everything to a form and then sending it to CHunique.php, which is the following (currently an incomplete test page for demonstration of problem):

```
<?php



@$con=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name") or die ("Could not    connect to the database. Please try again later.");

mysqli_set_charset($con,"UTF8");

$Err = "fine";

session_start();
$login = $_SESSION['account'];




$CHresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM CHstats");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($CHresult)) {

$thecharacters = $row['character'];

if (strtolower($character) === strtolower($thecharacters)) { $Err = " Character name already in use."; break; }; }
```

The problem here is that I do not get any response back from the server at all. It stays infinitely on its "progress" function, which is to say "Please wait . . . " This is true for ALL while loops that I attempt on the php page...the server just gets stuck in loading. This is a huge problem because I need to use a while loop to loop through all the characters in order to see if the user's name is unique or not.

Again, everything is working fine, including the image upload, EXCEPT for this check. This check is very important, and I'm wondering why every single while loop I try in the php page just results in an infinite load time?? Please help.

Also keep in mind I do not use JQuery.

Comment: Your PHP doesn't seem to echo a response anywhere ?

Comment: I really hope those aren't your real db credentials

Comment: I just see 1 while loop in your posted code. This while loop is just to fetch data and looks like there is no way it could cause infinite loop here (unless your data is extremely large with many rows to load, this will cause the delay and make you think something's being looped infinitely).

Comment: Check values of `$character` and `$thecharacters`

Comment: No those arent the real credentials of the database. I did not put in an echo response because the problem is the infinite load time; no echo response can be given because of this problem. Also, there are like 10 characters in the column, not a lot. The $character variable is fine, but I cannot check $thecharacters because of the infinite loading problem. Please continue helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! I actually solved it all on my own after several hours of frustration. The answer lies in my stupid AJAX conditional: if (xmlhttp.responseText.length <= 14). The responses were more than 14 characters and thus caused the server to load indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just change your query to do the work for you, doesn't really make sense to do the comparison in PHP

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM CHstats WHERE LOWER(character) = LOWER('%s')", $thecharacters);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   // duplicate character name
}
```

Also, are you sure that the while loop is what's causing your page to hang? It is very likely that the connection to mysql isn't being made or is taking a long time. If you haven't already, move a die statement around your code to see where it is getting hung up.

Comment: your code does not work for me, mainly because $thecharacters cannot be defined without using the while loop that causes an infinite load. Honestly, the code works fine if there are no while loops involved, so I am making a guess that that is what's going on.

Comment: actually, on second thought, I just redid your code to work without a while loop, and it still is having an infinite load time. I think the issue is that the php code infinitely loads if it checks anything in the database, which is very weird? Why would that be?

Comment: Did you put the die statement in to see how far it makes it before hanging? My guess would be it is hanging while connecting to the mysql server

Comment: It actually only hangs if the character submitted is a duplicate of a character already on the server. I don't understand why the code can't just see that one character is equal to another and then return an error? This is how it works for all my other error checks...